# Real time lightning strike API

Tags: api, weather

I'm looking for an API that will provide real-time lightning strike data in a metro area and searches have come up short. Please send me the link and an overview of your experience if you have worked with one in the past.....

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out, there are two big players:

1) Vaisala

2) NAPLN

We chose to use NAPLN.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend that you have a look at the [Vaisala Global Lightning Dataset GLD360](http://www.vaisala.com/en/products/thunderstormandlightningdetectionsystems/Pages/GLD360.aspx) system.